# Shell Execute From Explorer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Trying to follow this sample:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040520-00/?p=39243

```
void ShellExecuteFromExplorer(PCWSTR pszFile,    PCWSTR pszParameters = nullptr,    PCWSTR pszDirectory  = nullptr,    PCWSTR pszOperation  = nullptr,    int nShowCmd         = SW_SHOWNORMAL)
{
    CComPtr<IShellFolderViewDual> spFolderView;
    GetDesktopAutomationObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spFolderView));
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispShell;
    spFolderView->get_Application(&spdispShell);
    CComQIPtr<IShellDispatch2>(spdispShell)
       ->ShellExecute(CComBSTR(pszFile),
                      CComVariant(pszParameters ? pszParameters : L""),
                      CComVariant(pszDirectory ? pszDirectory : L""),
                      CComVariant(pszOperation ? pszOperation : L""),
                      CComVariant(nShowCmd));
}
```

In this case, how do i retrieve the `pid` from the process being launch from the `ShellExecute`?

Comment: [c++ - Get PID from ShellExecute - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620322/get-pid-from-shellexecute) ?

Comment: Is this ATL? -- --

Comment: for what you need exec process from explorer ? for what need it pid ? what is your real target ?

Comment: @RbMm "*for what you need exec process from explorer?*" - `IShellDispatch2::ShellExecute()` can be used to [launch an unelevated process from an elevated process](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) (which I know you already knew)

Comment: Yes, this is the point @RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau - in this case you can open explorer handle and use it as parent for new process. also can and use explorer token in call CreateProcessAsUser ( elevated process can got `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` )

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I'm aware, you already explained that in [Wait for the process started by IShellDispatch2.ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050455/wait-for-the-process-started-by-ishelldispatch2-shellexecute)

Answer (score 2):

not need use this way for create unelevated process. for instance we can use shell process (explorer) as parent for new process with help `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`. example of code

```
ULONG ExecFromShell(_In_opt_ PCWSTR lpApplicationName,
                    _Inout_opt_ PWSTR lpCommandLine)
{
    if (HWND hwnd = GetShellWindow())
    {
        ULONG dwProcessId, dwThreadId;
        if (dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId))
        {
            if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS|READ_CONTROL, 
                    FALSE, dwProcessId))
            {
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                STARTUPINFOEXW si { sizeof(si)};
                SIZE_T s = 0;
                ULONG dwError;

__0:
                switch (dwError = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
                    si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &s) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
                {
                case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                    if (!si.lpAttributeList)
                    {
                        si.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)alloca(s);
                        goto __0;
                    }
                    break;
                case NOERROR:
                    if (UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 0, 
                        PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS,
                        &hProcess, sizeof(hProcess), 0, 0))
                    {
                        ULONG cb = 0;
                        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa) };

__1:
                        switch (GetKernelObjectSecurity(hProcess, 
                            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
                            sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, cb, &cb) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
                        {
                        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                            if (!sa.lpSecurityDescriptor)
                            {
                                sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = alloca(cb);
                                goto __1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case NOERROR:
                            if (CreateProcessW(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, &sa, &sa, 
                                FALSE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, 0, 0, &si.StartupInfo, &pi))
                            {
                                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dwError = GetLastError();
                            }
                            break;
                        }                       

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwError = GetLastError();
                    }

                    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList);
                    break;
                }
                
                CloseHandle(hProcess);

                return dwError;
            }

            return GetLastError();
        }
    }

    return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - this is not endless loop. this is my technique

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing. It would be less code if you just called `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` twice.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - twice in src code :) and this will be not less code - try it. i prefer such style. this also will be called twice in runtime, but only once in src

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, how do i retrieve the `pid` from the process being launch from the `ShellExecute`?

You can't.  just like `::ShellExecute()`, `IShellDispatch2::ShellExecute()` simply does not provide any information about the new process.